# Does splits sequences need to be short exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am reading Aluffi Algebra and I see that split sequence is a special case of  a short exact sequence. This is my first time seeing this and due to a natural curiosity, I wonder is there a "split" sequence that is not short exact or exact in general?

Comment: Generally I think the point of split exact sequences is that it allows you to express the middle term in terms of the outer two terms, something that isn't guaranteed from any s.e.s. It's not clear how to define what it means for a sequence to "split" if there wasn't an exact sequence to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of suspect that there is no such thing since this is just a curiosity in the first place.